# Find the sum of the series $\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}.\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{5}.\frac{1}{3!}+\cdots$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Find the sum of the series $$\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}.\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{5}.\frac{1}{3!}+\cdots$$

I found that the n-th term of the series is $\frac{1}{n+2}.\frac{1}{n!}$ , but I am unable to find the sum.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/q/126739 for similar question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\frac{1}{(n+2)n!}=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}-\frac{1}{(n+2)!}$$

Now telescope.

Comment: That's more like a complete answer :~). +1.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Well, not quite.  And thank you for the up vote!  Much appreciative.

Comment: Dr. Mv what steps did you execute to express it in this form. @Dr.MV

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla  $$\frac{1}{n!(n+2)}=\frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}=\frac{n+2-1}{(n+2)!}$$